# Typeahead.js -> Token different from value doesn't work for me

Tags: token, typeahead.js

this is my data

```
[{"Id": "21", "name": "Šport", "value": "Šport","tokens": ["Šport", "Sport"]}]
```

I want to the data to be found even if user does not use 'special' characters so it doesn't matter if he types in "Sport" or "Šport"' the data "Šport" will be found.

Should this be working or maybe any workaround sugestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the complete typeahead code you are using along with the parameters you are adding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work. If it doesn't work, then I would start by checking whether this is *really* the data the Typeahead sees.

Is this `remote`? If so, have you made sure this is indeed what you server returns and what your client sees? Look at the Firefox/Chrome developer tools network requests to be sure.

If not, maybe you have stale (old) data in local storage (where Typeahead caches stuff)? Remove any dataset `name` just to be sure.

Finally, to verify that it works, try this exact data with `local.

Comment: God bless you. The data has been cached by Typeahead in local storage. To deny that (good for testing) include 'ttl: 0' parameter in you prefetch block.

Comment: :) Thanks. Or remove `name:`